# Problem with Network Manager not selecting Ethernet connection

Tags: networking, drivers

Gentlemen:

After I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, I experienced no problems at all. Unfortunately, an update on 10/6/2018 caused an error in my NetworkManager.conf (location etc/Networkmanager) toggling [ifupdown], managed to false rather than true. I was able to correct that problem as you can see below.

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=true (this was set to false by the update)

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

Then an update on 10/13/2018 caused a situation between WiFi and ethernet. My eth0 connection will only work when I restart the laptop. As long as I do not close the cover (suspend). If I do close the cover (suspend), the WiFi becomes the active connection. I can see the wired connection (eth0) properties and they are all correct and should be active, but I am unable to bring the connection up. I have tried resetting the network manager and using the ifdown/up commands as viewed in some of the Ubuntu forums but nothing seems to work. The only way that I can use the wired connection is by restarting the laptop. A word of note, I have a dual boot for some Windows programs that I can not run in Ubuntu. I have absolutley no issue with the wired connection in Windows.

I ran the following commands to provide you with some information:

*sudo uname -a, sudo lsmod, & sudo lspci*

The results follow below.

**mario@mario-inspiron:~$ sudo uname -a**

[sudo] password for mario:

```
Linux mario-inspiron 4.15.0-36-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 24 16:19:09 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**mario@mario-inspiron:~$ sudo lsmod**

```
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 77824  4
cmac                   16384  1
ccm                    20480  3
bnep                   20480  2
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
uvcvideo               86016  0
ath3k                  20480  0
hid_multitouch         20480  0
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             548864  34 btrtl,btintel,bnep,btbcm,rfcomm,ath3k,btusb
ecdh_generic           24576  2 bluetooth
dell_smbios_wmi        16384  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
dell_laptop            20480  0
dell_smbios_smm        16384  0
dcdbas                 16384  1 dell_smbios_smm
intel_rapl             20480  0
dell_smm_hwmon         16384  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             212992  0
kvm                   598016  1 kvm_intel
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
pcbc                   16384  0
aesni_intel           188416  4
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
intel_cstate           20480  0
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek   106496  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
dell_wmi               16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 dell_wmi
dell_smbios            16384  4 dell_wmi,dell_laptop,dell_smbios_wmi,dell_smbios_smm
input_leds             16384  0
serio_raw              16384  0
snd_hda_intel          40960  8
dell_wmi_descriptor    16384  2 dell_wmi,dell_smbios_wmi
joydev                 24576  0
arc4                   16384  2
snd_hda_codec         126976  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           81920  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
ath9k                 151552  0
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
ath9k_common           36864  1 ath9k
snd_pcm                98304  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
ath9k_hw              471040  2 ath9k,ath9k_common
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
ath                    28672  3 ath9k_hw,ath9k,ath9k_common
mac80211              778240  1 ath9k
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
cfg80211              622592  4 mac80211,ath9k,ath,ath9k_common
lpc_ich                24576  0
mei_me                 40960  0
snd                    81920  27 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
dell_rbtn              16384  0
shpchp                 36864  0
mei                    90112  1 mei_me
soundcore              16384  1 snd
mac_hid                16384  0
dw_dmac                16384  0
dw_dmac_core           24576  1 dw_dmac
sch_fq_codel           20480  2
parport_pc             36864  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
ip_tables              28672  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                40960  2
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
hid_rmi                20480  0
rmi_core               77824  1 hid_rmi
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  2 uvcvideo,rmi_core
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  2 uvcvideo,rmi_core
videobuf2_core         40960  3 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2,rmi_core
videodev              184320  4 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2,rmi_core
media                  40960  2 uvcvideo,videodev
i915                 1617920  20
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        172032  1 i915
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
r8169                  86016  0
ahci                   36864  3
drm                   401408  15 i915,drm_kms_helper
libahci                32768  1 ahci
mii                    16384  1 r8169
wmi                    24576  4 dell_wmi,wmi_bmof,dell_wmi_descriptor,dell_smbios_wmi
i2c_hid                20480  0
hid                   118784  5 i2c_hid,hid_generic,usbhid,hid_rmi,hid_multitouch
video                  45056  3 dell_wmi,dell_laptop,i915
```

**mario@mario-inspiron:~$ sudo lspci**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
06:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07)
```

mario@mario-inspiron:~$

Comment: What's in `/etc/network/interfaces`?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You may have fallen prey to a timing problem, esp if you're running off of SSD...</strike>

If you're running on a SSD, you run the risk of things  booting faster than the network is coming online and then you'll need to modify the following file: `/etc/systemd/system/network-online.target.wants/NetworkManager-wait-online.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Network Manager Wait Online
Documentation=man:nm-online(1)
Requires=NetworkManager.service
After=NetworkManager.service
Before=network-online.target
```

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nm-online -s -q --timeout=**60**
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=network-online.target

and change the timeout from `30` to `60`. Reboot.

**Update #1:**

Set NetworkManager.conf `[ifupdown] managed=true` back to `false`. It's all working now.

Comment: Hello heynnema. I tried the change for timeout from 30 to 60. Unfortunately, that did not allow the Ethernet connection to connect, either. In fact, it forced the WiFi to connect and remain there after reboot. I changed the timeout back to 30 and the Ethernet connection connects upon reboot but the original problem still exists. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: @MarioFusaro did you change ifupdown back to false and then reboot? You still might need the 30/60 patch. Report back to "@heynnema"

Comment: Yes, I did do the change before the reboot and then I returned all the settings to the original and rebooted again. Strangely, the problem seems to have resolved. I am always connecting to the Ethernet now as long as the cable is plugged in. When I unplug the cable, it switches to WiFi as it should. When I plug in the cable, it switches back to Ethernet. I'll see how this plays out for a few days.

Comment: @MarioFusaro please remember to accept my answer if it was helpful. Thanks!